# Reset JavaScript Counter?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to program a counter into a website via JavaScript and have found exactly what I need here:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

What I am trying to do is count down from 30 to 0. Once the counter reaches zero I want to display an alert. I have been able to get this to work. The only function that I cannot figure out is how to reset my counter back to 30 on a certain button push. I have tried code such as `document.gameForm.txt.value=30;` but for whatever reason 30 does not replace whatever text is currently in the box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I understand it, you need to call [`clearTimeout()`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) function to reset the counter eg:

```
var t = setTimeout("alert('I am displayed after 3 seconds!')", 3000);
```

Later you can reset it like:

```
clearTimeout(t);
```

Comment: That is correct. The problem is that this will reset the timer to 0, when I want it to reset to 30.

Comment: @user: After resetting, you can specify that much time with `setTimeout`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I don't know why I was having so much trouble. I just took another look and the solution was actually quite simple.